# How can I know is returned a new document or not in the method findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I know is returned a new document or not?

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate(
  {user_id: 123},
  {last_activity_at: new Date(), is_blocked: false, ...ctx.from},
  {upsert: true, new: true}
)
```

I have to create a variable `is_new_user: true`.

Comment: `new: true` itself always returns a new document so you do not need do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

*It will return new document:*

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate(
  {user_id: 123},
  {last_activity_at: new Date(), is_blocked: false, ...ctx.from},
  {upsert: true, new: true, `returnNewDocument: true`}
)
```

Comment: How can I find out whether this is a new document or an old one?

Comment: as per mongodb documentation, it returns new document when this property is set. check here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db.collection.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: No, I need to return the document in any case. But you need to find out if it was just created. How to do it?